# Identified xpath is not working in testng,if the xpath is in first line of the method logout. the same xpath is working without using testng

Tags: testng

Identified xpath is not working in testng, if the xpath is in first line of the method logout. The same xpath is working without using testng.

I am getting error:

Unable to locate element: `{"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='level1 menu static']/li[2]/a"}`

Program is below:

```
@Test
public void login(){
driver1.findElement(By.id("txtUsername")).sendKeys("***");
driver1.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("***");
driver1.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
System.out.println("Logged into the application");
}       

@Test
public void Logout() throws InterruptedException 
{   
    WebElement l =driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='level1 menu static']/li[2]/a"));
            act.moveToElement(l).perform();                 
   driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='level1 menu static']/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();    
                }}
```

Please help me to identify the problem

Comment: You need to wait for the element, make sure you are logged in before logging out.

Comment: What's with the extra `ul/li[1]` in the second line ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should make sure the tests are executed in the correct order. This can be achieved in several ways:

1. Implicitly set test method order in testng.xml file like this:

   ```
   <test name="Login/logout test" preserve-order="true">
       <classes>
           <class name="com.test.LoginLogout">
               <methods>
                   <include name="login" />
                   <include name="Logout" />
               </methods>
           </class>
       </classes>
   </test>
   ```
2. Use additional attributes of the @Test annotation:

   ```
   @Test(dependsOnMethods="login")
   public void Logout() throws InterruptedException
   ```

Secondly, you should make sure the element is accessible when the logout test is executed. This can be achieved, using some impementation of wait (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11738528/3069490) for some examples), like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver1, timeoutInSeconds);    
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class='level1 menu static']/li[2]/a"));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot.my code is working fine when i used 2nd option using @test annotation.

Comment: @saran - please mark this as the accepted answer.